# Slack Next Generation Platform in message event listener

Tags: slack, slack-api, deno

I was developing a bot using the Slack next-generation platform. which will take messages from the app and send them to targeted channels. But I am not able to assign a channel ID for the user or app chat channel. Because the app chat channel ID is different for each user, is there any way to add an event listener?

In the below event trigger, we can see that we need to assign a channel ID to trigger the event. But how do you assign the channel ID when users chat with the app?

```
const triggerResponse = await client.workflows.triggers.create<
    typeof SendMessageWorkflow.definition
  >({
    type: TriggerTypes.Event,
    name: "Event On bot app chat",
    description: "responds to user when they chat with bot",
    workflow: `#/workflows/${SendMessageWorkflow.definition.callback_id}`,
    event: {
      event_type: TriggerEventTypes.MessagePosted,
      channel_ids: ["Your channel ID"], // not able to assign channel ID for user to app chat box
      filter: {
        version: 1,
        root: {
          statement: "{{data.text}} CONTAINS help",
        },
      },
    },
    inputs: {
      channel: {
        value: channel,
      },
      message: {
        value: TriggerContextData.Event.MessagePosted.text,
      },
      user: {
        value: TriggerContextData.Event.MessagePosted.user_id,
      },
    },
  });
```

I know we can use Bolt to solve this issue, but is there any way on the next-gen platform?

In bolt app We can listen all message and check the channel_type. Like

```
app.message( async ({ message, say, event, client, context, logger }) => {

  

  if ( event.channel_type === "im" ) {

    try {

      // My task

    } catch (error) {
      await say(`Bot is not working, Please!`);
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this on the next-gen platform?